# Making an int be multiple values?

Tags: c#, for-loop, int

Is there any way to have a int value that is multiple values?
Under here you can see the code, im doing a minigame as a proof of concept.
currently i have x happen at loop number 4 and y happens at loop number 9.

Is there any way to repeat theese actions on other loops wihout maing it a huge mess like this: i == 4||i == 14 || i == 18

what im trying to ask is if its possible to just write i == a
and then have a be multiple values.

If you havent figured already, im quite the beginner at C#, so if you can explain it in a easy to understand way, i would be very thankfull.
If what i wrote is a bit hard to understand, then im sorry for not being a native english speaker, just ask if you're unsure of what i mean.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    string input;
    input = Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();
    Console.Clear();
    if (input == "A") Animation.frame1();
    else Animation.fall();
    if (i == 4) Animation.blocklow2();
    if (i == 9) Animation.blockhigh2();
    input = Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();
    Console.Clear();
    if (input == "W" && i == 4) Animation.blockjump();
    if (input == "S" && i == 9) Animation.blockduck();
    if (input == "D" && i != 4 && i != 9) Animation.frame2();
    else if (input != "W" && i == 4) Animation.fall();
    else if (input != "S" && i == 9) Animation.smack();
    if (i == 3) Animation.blocklow();
    if (i == 8) Animation.blockhigh();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do `if (new int[] { 4, 14, 18 }.Contains(i))` to check for multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

Store a list of ints that you want to check against and then use `.Contains`

```
List<int> frame2ints = new List<int>{4,9};
if (input == "D" && !frame2ints.Contains(i)) Animation.frame2();
```

Answer (score 0):

In certain situations you can perform bitwise tests to see whether some bits are set in your number:

```
if ((x & 4) != 0)
{
    // This case covers numbers
    // 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, and many others...
}
```

General answer to your question is NO, and it only makes sense to use additional knowledge about the values you are testing and then use that knowledge.

Another option is to test whether a number belongs to a sequence, like HHLV said in other answer.

So, how did you get to values 4, 14 and 18?

Comment: Based on the code, it looks like animation that runs at certain times in a loop, guessing i is the time for frames in the loop. My guess is OP is trying to reuse the animation asset by checking i.

Comment: I don't think bitwise works so well for this, since OP wants specific numbers, bitwise would give more numbers than OP wants, or need a very complex check, which is what OP is trying to avoid.